# CakePHP Email could not be sent

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I Just moved from a test enviroment to a new Webhost, and now my application throws errors when I try to send a mail.
I am using CakePHP and the CakeMail function to send this email.

This is the last part of the Error Message:

```
Could not send email.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php line 46 → MailTransport->_mail(string, string, string, string, null)
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1065 → MailTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Controller/UsersController.php line 204 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → UsersController->add()
```

Temporarily, you can reproduce the error by registering (just put anything in, I don't mind) on this webpage: http://eevent.ch/index.php/users/add

My Code looks like this:

```
$emailstring = 'emailstring';
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->emailFormat('both');
$Email->from(array('info@eevent.ch' => 'info'));
$Email->to(array( username => usermail));
$Email->subject(__('Registrierung auf Eevent.ch'));
$Email->send($emailstring);
```

I am Assuming that my code is correct as it works just fine on the test server.

From searching this error on StackOverflow I have checked a few things.
I set the $email->from with an array.
I checked my phpinfo, it does include 
sendmail_from   me@localhost.com    me@localhost.com
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Is it possible that me not setting a Header produces the Error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$Email->to` is the code which used in real app

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but I used fake data in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
$Email->to(array( username => usermail));
```

there should be string or variables passed to an array. Like here:

```
$Email->to(array( 'username' => $usermail));
```

And did you configured email.php in /app/config/mail.php ?

Comment: Though it might not be clear from my example, but I did set all my variables correctly. After talking to the hoster, it turns out it was a hosting problem. Thanks for the effort though!